# Creating activities architecture Android

Tags: android, architecture

while creating application I faced a architecture problem. I want to do like this : [image]

I thing everything is shown clearly. By the way. While app user is in Menu activity, and if he press back button, (not Logout method) he does not log out. 
I'm newbie in android, could someone give me an advice ?
what methods should i use ?

```
                Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                        "com.project.simplify.NewReviewActivity");
                menuIntent.putExtra("user", user);
                menuIntent.putExtra("link", realLink);
                startActivity(menuIntent);
```

here is the Logout method :

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(loginIntent);

                finish();
```

How i ***solved*** my problem :

```
public static MenuActivity MenuActivityObject;

onCreate()
{
    MenuActivityObject = this;
}
```

now use that object in logout method to finish menu activity:

```
Logout()
{
    MenuActivity.MenuActivityObject.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on Logout from any of the `Activity` to launch `LoginActivity` use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` . This will clear the all the previous `Activity` in stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

When the user press BACK on `MenuActivity` , the system will `finish` the `MenuActivity` and user will be taken to the `LoginActivity` as per your architecture . It will work perfectly

Comment: maybe you misunderstood me. i don't want to log out from application on back button pressed. The only case i want to logout, when i press the button to start method logout

Comment: back button won't logout. Only when logout button is clicked add my code

Comment: if i add this code and execute it from ActivityOne= i go to login screen. And if i press back button there, i go to MenuActivity again.. That is the problem

Comment: This should work perfectly. Can you post your ? Just post how you start all the Activity

Comment: What is NewReviewActivity ? Where do you launch `LoginActivity` when logout from `Activity one`

Comment: NewReviewActivity== ActivityOne . Loginactivity is Launcher in manifest.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51845/discussion-between-libin-and-user3416113)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to logout when user presses back button, you can ovverride "onBackPressed" in "MenuActivity" and call "logout method".

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you not close the manu activity when start the Activity 1.

for example

MenuActivity

oncreate{

```
Intent inte = new Intent(context,Activity1.class);
startActivity(inte);
finish();
}
```

if you don't call "finish()" the MenuActivity is still alive. Post your source code.

Comment: but why i should kill it if i can hold it like a parent activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logout method start LoginActivity and kill the last Activity launched , Activity1 , Activity2 or Activity3.

If you don't close the MenuActivity when start the next Activity , MenuActivity remain on the stack , so when you do logout , you start LoginActivity but if user press back button the system replace LoginActivity with the last Activity present on the stack , in this case MenuActivity.

Comment: Yes, i do understand. And how may i kill that MenuActivity with logout method ?

Answer (score 0):

change you logout code like this

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);

                finish();
```